# Jquery finding a specific H4 with no id nor name nor class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

i have a simple question about JQuery...

I have a main `<div>` containing some divs, which have dynamical ids. each child div has a `<h4>` tag in it. These `h4` does not have any id, nor class, nor name. They just have some text in it.

Here is what i'm talking about :

```
<div id="main_div">
   <div id ="div01">
      <h4>Sometext01</h4>
   </div>
   <div id ="div02">
      <h4>Sometext02</h4>
   </div>
   <div id ="div03">
      <h4>Special Text!!!</h4>
   </div>
   <div id ="div04">
      <h4>Sometext04</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the parent div's id of the h4 which text is "Special text!!!" (so, here, in this example, it is div03).

But, unfortunately, these ids are auto generated (by Sugarcrm, for those who know), and i can't know by advance the id's name. So that is why i have to pass by the h4.

I know i can use the jQuery function below to pass through all h4

```
allMyH4.each()
```

And i know i can use the jQuery function below to find the parent of my desired h4

```
myFoundH4.parent()
```

But i'm getting some trouble on searching the h4 by their text() (or html() )

Could you please help me on that?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT few hours later :**

Thanks to @Bhushan , i could do what i really wanted. It just has a restriction : my user MUST not change h4 texts NOR giving several h4 the same name containing my string.
For another solution, try @rory too, it did not work for me, but it had been tested by others, and it seems to be better than contains.

Comment: maybe with `match()` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

Comment: What's unique about that `h4`? Is it its text value?

Comment: in this case you can only find them by their text or html, or by their order (the order they are implemented on your code)

Comment: @TCHdvlp My humble request is to stop sharing links to w3schools. Worst place to learn web technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
var parentId = $('main_div').find('h4:contains("Special Text!!!")').parent().attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @bhushan-Kawadkar , for my specific application, it works! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter()`:

```
var $h4 = $('h4').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Special Text!!!';
});
console.log($h4.parent().prop('id'));
```

This will ensure an exact match on the text property, not a partial match as the `:contains` selector will give. `filter` should also be faster.

Comment: the OP specifically said he doesn't wanna use `text()` or `html()`, am I missing something?

Comment: @AminJafari he said he was having problems with them, not that he didn't want to use them.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, it was a good beginning... unless it gives me "undefined". And if i just try to sort the $h4.parent(), it displays .. all the parents of all the h4... so the filter does not seem to work. any idea? (i'm trying with contains, even if it is less effective than filter)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)?

```
var divId = $("h4:contains('Special Text!!!')").parent().attr('id');
```

---

If there's other `<h4>` tags containing text which includes your *Special Text!!!*, but you don't want to select them, you can use `.filter()` as [@Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24801139/2685386) says:

```
var divId = $("h4:contains('Special Text!!!')").filter(function(i, elt) {
    return $(elt).text() === 'Special Text!!!';
}).parent().attr('id');
```

However if you have multiple `<h4>`s with this text, it *could* still match multiple elements.

Comment: then it would select "123Special Text!!!abcd" as well, if it is implemented in one of the h4s!

Comment: @AminJafari True, it would. Question makes it look like that wouldn't be an issue, but if it is, it's not that hard to work around

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h4").each(function(inx, elem){
    var pattern = "Special Text!!!", el = $(elem);
    if(el.text() == pattern){
         console.info(el.parent().attr("id"));
    }
});
```

**Update:** Roy McCrossan has a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/3xQqa/1/)

```
$("h4").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() === 'Special Text!!!')
    {
        var pid = $(this).parents().attr("id");     
        alert(pid); 
    }
});
```